# How to animate div for a fixed (offset) position using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple DIV that I would like to move (animate) to a known position on the screen ("fixed"). I have found that animate() method in jQuery moves the element **in** the given pixels but this is not what I'm looking for. Example:

My DIV's name is "frameArea" and I would like to move it to offset top: 5px / left: 260px. If I write the following, It will move the DIV  **5px down and 260px to the right**. What am I doing wrong? Is it possible?

```
 $("#frameArea")
       .animate({
           left: 260px,
           top: 5px
        }, 5000);
```

I'm new to HTML and jQuery, so please be gentle :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example. Make sure u start the animation after the element is loaded. May be in document.ready

[Example](http://jsbin.com/eputib/1/edit)

Comment: Thanks so much! It seems the the "position" attribute was missing for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your code of top: 5px and left: 260px is saying where to begin the element. The starting point is 5px from the top and 260px from the left.

If you want the element to appear -5px (so 5px is cut off by the top of the browser window) type:

```
top: -5px;
```